# State in React code to be displayed in browser

Tags: reactjs

how do I display the result of this code in my browser

code to be displayed in browser

import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class ManagedControlDemo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: ""};
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({message: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <legend>Type something here</legend>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.message}
            autoFocus />
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<ManagedControlDemo/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That last line in your code is telling React to "grab the DOM element in my HTML file with the ID of 'app' and render this ManagedControlDemo component I've made into it."

So note the HTML in the following snippet:

```js
class ManagedControlDemo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: ""};
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({message: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <legend>Type something here</legend>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.message}
            autoFocus />
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ManagedControlDemo/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```